# Finding a .bmp file with java class ImageIO read method

Tags: java, bmp, javax.imageio

I have the following test class Test_Retina that is testing a method in a class Retina called "seeBMPImage" by first retrieving a .bmp image. However I am getting a null pointer exception and I don't understand why because a image 66 by 66 pixels wide is named "2.bmp" and it is in the same package as classes "Retina.java" and "Test_Retina.java"

```
public class Test_Retina extends junit.framework.TestCase {
private Retina retina;

public void setUp() {
VisionCell[][] visionCells = new VisionCell[66][66];
// this.retina = new Retina(visionCells);
}

public void test_seeBMPImage() throws IOException {
this.retina.seeBMPImage("2.bmp"); <-- !!GETTING A NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION!!
// ...
}
```

}

```
public class Retina {
private VisionCell[][] visionCells;

public void seeBMPImage(String BMPFileName) throws IOException {
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPFileName));
    int color = image.getRGB(1, 1);
if (color == Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
    System.out.println("black");
    } else {
        System.out.println("white");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When getting an exception, it's usually a good idea post (relevant parts of) the stracktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment the line:

```
// this.retina = new Retina(visionCells);
```

in the setUp method.

Currently this.retina is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the resource name with the fully qualified package name, even if the resource is in the same package as the class in which you invoke it. getClass().getResource() is essentially the same as this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...) which uses the ClassLoader that was used to load the current class to load the resource, the class itself does not load the resource. So if your resource is in the package test.p1.p2, for example, you want to use the resource name "test/p1/p2/2.bmp"

Comment: I just tried this.retina.seeBMPImage("tests/model/2.bmp"); and I am getting the exact same error. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Instead of `this.retina.seeBMPImage("tests/model/2.bmp");` try `this.retina.seeBMPImage("/tests/model/2.bmp");`

Comment: This makes no sense. If the resource was `null`, `ImageIO.read()` would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.